# The geometric and/or categorical interpretation of ramification theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, arithmetic-geometry

We all know the ramification theory (index, inertia, filtration, etc.) of Dedekind domains and valuations. How should one find its geometric (as in covers of say schemes) and/or categorical (as in Grothendieck's Galois categories) analogues?

Comment: A professor pointed me to https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010103.pdf, reading it right now, and will update later.

Comment: The question is slightly vague, are you asking what ramification means in geometric terms?

Comment: @AbstractNonsense mostly in categorical terms

Comment: Do you know already about ramification of morphisms of (schematic) curves?

Comment: @AbstractNonsense like as the ramifiedness in one of the definitions of etaleness?

Comment: Yes etale morphisms are unramified

Comment: @AbstractNonsense but i want to know how to say these in categorical language